# How to get Per Month data from firestore with JS

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to get the Per month Water data from firestore for all the documents i try but nothing work i think i can get data by the help of timestamp and water field which are present in my database can anyone help me with it.
This is my database.
[image]

I try this from the last answer but nothing is showing in console

```js
const cloudDb = app.firestore();
var time="1638297000"
var lasttime="1640845799"

cloudDb.collection('AKVO_RND')
    .where('timestamp', '>=', time)
    .where('timestamp', '<=', lasttime )
    .orderBy('timestamp', 'desc')
    .get().then(function(querySnapshot){
      querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc){
        water= (doc.data().water)
        console.log(water);
      })
    })
```

Comment: On your update: the timestamp values are numbers in your database, but you're passing them as strings in the query, so those values don't match and the query returns no results. Instead, pass them as numbers, e.g.: `cloudDb.collection('AKVO_RND').where('timestamp', '>=', 1638297000).where('timestamp', '<=', 1640845799 )...`

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I tried this but i didn't get anything on console

Comment: Did you check the number of digits in your code versus that in the database? They seem off by about 1000x, so they're probably in different units.

Answer (score 2):

You can make query something like this with help of firebase functions:

```
firestore().collection('AKVO_RND')
    .where('timestamp', '>=', time)
    .where('timestamp', '<=', lastdate)
    .orderBy('timestamp', 'desc')
    .get();
```

Make sure of using [runTimeOptions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#reduce_the_number_of_cold_starts). It will allow your function to run more time than recommended time